# Access scoped slot from component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I got this component:

```
<template>
  <Popover v-slot="{ open }">
    <PopoverButton>
      {{ title }}
    </PopoverButton>
    <div v-if="computedOpen">
      <PopoverPanel static>
        <slot name="popover"></slot>
      </PopoverPanel>
    </div>
  </Popover>
</template>

<script>
import {Popover, PopoverButton, PopoverPanel} from '@headlessui/vue'
import {computed, ref, watch} from 'vue'
import {useRoute} from 'vue-router'

export default {
  name: 'DropdownMenuButton',
  mixins: [slots],
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
  },
  components: {
    Popover,
    PopoverButton,
    PopoverPanel,
    ChevronDownIcon,
  },
  setup(props) {
    const isOpen = ref(null);
    const route = useRoute()

    watch(route, () => {
      isOpen.value = false;
    });

    const computedOpen = computed(() => {
      let open = ...? //this is missing...
      return isOpen.value && open.value;
    });

    return {
      computedOpen
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

This component makes use of [headless UI's popover](https://headlessui.dev/vue/popover).

Now I'd like to close the popover once the route changes. While the route-change is being detected fine, I can not access the `<Popover>`'s `open` value in the `setup()` method to determine, whether `computedOpen` should return `true` or `false`.

My question: How can I access `v-slot="{ open }` in the computed value?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.

Think about it:

1. Everything inside `<Popover>` element (the slot content) is compiled by Vue to a function returning the virtual DOM representation of the content
2. This function is passed to the `Popover` component as `slots.default` and when the `Popover` component is rendering, it calls that function passing the `open` value as an argument

So `open` value is `Popover` component's internal state and is only accessible inside the template (ie. slot render function)

So I think your best bet is throw away the `computed` idea and just use the `open` value directly in the template or use `method` instead, passing `open` as an argument

```html
    <div v-if="isOpen && open">
      <PopoverPanel static>
        <slot name="popover"></slot>
      </PopoverPanel>
    </div>
```

```html
    <div v-if="isPanelOpen(open)">
      <PopoverPanel static>
        <slot name="popover"></slot>
      </PopoverPanel>
    </div>
```